# Strange (for me) return statement - can't find any information on google about it

Tags: c++, recursion

I made a C++ program using recursion which returns the largest digit in a number.
I made it work my way, but I found an alternative:

```
int cifmax(int n) {
    if(n <= 9)
        return n;
    return max(n % 10, cifmax(n / 10));
}
```

How does that second return work?

Comment: I assume it's the call `cifmax(n / 10)` you're wondering about? Then please do some research about *recursion*.

Comment: Recursion is often better avoided. Despite what academia claims.

Comment: I don't get the second return at all. I never saw a return like that and I don't get how it works. Can you please give me some documentation if you know what it is about?

Comment: @Ron yeah I'm having a really hard time mastering it but I have to do it for school. So please help me understand it :)

Comment: The subject is too broad for SO format.

Comment: @Ron I'm talking about my specific case. Can you explain to me how does this return work?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu What part are you having problems with? Have you looked up what `max` does? Do you know what `%` does?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Wow. I thought I'm missing something and I can call a function in that way. I never saw max as a function. I thought this returns a max=n%10 and then calls cifmax, or something like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ron agreed, but for learning, it's usually situations where an iterative operation will do.  I remember learning about Factorial recursive algorithm.  People were understanding it.  Then the professor showed the best algorithm was using a `for` loop.  Agreed it's just a tool.  When you have a hammer in your hand, everything starts looking like a nail.  Hammers are great, but not for every task (e.g. recursion is a great, but where applicable).  But you have to learn WHAT it is first, then UNDERSTAND it, then learn WHEN and when NOT to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of this code as being equivalent to the following, more verbose version:

```
int cifmax(int n) {
    if (n <= 9){
        return n; // trivial base case
    } else {
        int currentdigit = n % 10; // the least significant digit
        int otherdigits = n / 10; // other digits past the least significant
        int maxofotherdigits = cifmax(otherdigits); // make the recursive call

        // compute maximum of the two
        if (currentdigit > maxofotherdigits){
            return currentdigit;
        } else {
            return maxofotherdigits;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the following snippet:

```
if (currentdigit > maxofotherdigits){
    return currentdigit;
} else {
    return maxofotherdigits;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
return std::max(currentdigit, maxofotherdigits);
```

where [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) returns the larger of its two arguments.

Comment: I didn't realise max is a function because I'm not using it at school. I thought this returns a max=n%10 and then calls cifmax, or something like this. Thanks a lot.